# School exercice in c about prime numbers

Tags: c

Make a program that asks the user for an integer and says if the
number is prime or not. A number greater than 1 is prime if only
is divisible by 1 and by itself. Then, it will tell us what the prime number is.
example:

- Enter a number: 8

> 8 is not first. The first one immediately superior to 8 is 11.

- Enter a number: 5

> 5 is first. The first one immediately above 5 is 7.

I can only solve first part.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int num, i;
  do {
    printf("Enter a numer: ");
    scanf("%d", & num);
  }
  while (num < 1);
  for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0)
      printf("Its prime");
  }
  if (num % 1 == 0 && num % num == 0)
    printf("Not prime");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: thats c not c# - it should be easy for you to do.. how would you as a human work it out

Comment: The "while" is used to prevent negative numbers from being entered.

Comment: Necesito solucionar la segunda parte del ejercicio. In this code I need to know which is the first (prime) number immediately above the first one we find

Comment: From Review: Your question is [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, and you need first to do some effort by yourself. If you can't even get started, ask your teacher for help. Isolate your questions into specific programming snippets, and then search the for answers. In case you need a course or tutorial, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask it. We wish you good luck in your study. See: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You need an outer loop for the primality test, starting with `num + 1` and repeating until you have found a prime number. The number input can be improved - it has holes in it. You must check the return value from `scanf` too, which must be `1` (the number of items scanned).

Comment: If I run your code with the input "16", the output is "Its primeIts primeIts primeNot prime". So it seems that so far you have not solved the first part. Perhaps you should start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic. Not tested

```
        #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int num, i, flag = 0;
        printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        int isPrime=IsPrime(num)
        if(isPrime==0){
        numNext=num+1;
        int nextPrimeNum=checkNextPrime(numNext);
        }
    }

    int IsPrime(int num){
        for(i = 2; i <= num/2; ++i)
        {
            // condition for nonprime number
            if(num%i == 0)
            {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (num == 1) 
        {
            flag=1;//neither prime nor composite
        }   

        return flag;

    }
    int checkNextPrime(int numNext){

        int isNextPrime=IsPrime(numNext)
        if(isNextPrime==0){
            printf("This is the required output :"numNext);
            return numNext;
        }
        else{
            numNext=numNext+1;
            checkNextPrime(int numNext)
        }   
    }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is also a copy of someone else's code and _not_ the OP's code.  In addition, your indentation is awful - please tidy it up and explain how this answers OP's question.

Comment: In this code I need to know which is the first (prime) number immediately above the first one we find.